# SWIG does not support include_next GNU directive

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to generate python bindings, using swig, for a library written in C++.

When I run on Debian GNU/Linux 10

```
swig -I/usr/include \
    -I/usr/include/c++/8 \
    -I/usr/include/c++/8/tr1 \
    -I/usr/include/linux \
    -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu \
    -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/8 \
    -I/usr/share/swig3.0/python \
    -I$(KALDI_ROOT)/tools/openfst/src/include \
    -I$(KALDI_ROOT)/src \
    -includeall -c++ -python ConstArpaLmRescoring.i
```

the output is

```
/usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75: Error: Unknown SWIG preprocessor directive: include_next (if this is a block of target language code, delimit it with %{ and %})
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/std_abs.h:38: Error: Unknown SWIG preprocessor directive: include_next (if this is a block of target language code, delimit it with %{ and %})
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32: Error: CPP #error "This file requires compiler and library support \
for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled \
with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.". Use the -cpperraswarn option to continue swig processing.
/usr/include/c++/8/cmath:45: Error: Unknown SWIG preprocessor directive: include_next (if this is a block of target language code, delimit it with %{ and %})
make: *** [Makefile:38: all] Error 1
```

Files including `include_next` directive are `cmath` `complex.h` `cstdlib` `stdlib.h` `tgmath.h` `fenv.h` `math.h` `bits/std_abs.h`

What solution do you recommend to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `-includeall`.  That attempts to make swig wrappers for every function in every header file included, recursively.  You normally only want the functions in your custom API headers.

Comment: What if I need `-importall` - I need the C++ STL library?

Comment: It seems that I am supposed to be using SWIG's own STL implementation